# How to get rid of the "Other..."-Account on the login screen?

Tags: snow-leopard, user-account, login

Suddenly my MBP shows an "Other..."-Account on the login screen. I searched for a solution to get rid of it and found a couple of answers that say I have somehow activated/enabled the root user. All I did was using a couple of trivial sudo-commands at the command-line, but nothing experimental or which I am unfamiliar with...

The suggested solutions said I need to deactivate the root user in the Directory Utilities but it was not activated.

Are there any other solutions to get rid of this "Other..."-Account?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232449/remove-other-from-login-screen

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the `sudo /usr/bin/defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool false` in the terminal? This turns off showing some of the other user types.

Doing some additional research, it looks like this has been somewhat addressed in this post on https://superuser.com/questions/70156/hide-users-from-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-logon-screen