# Extra login in on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an “other” login on my computer that I can’t seem to get rid of. I try to delete it by clicking on the minus in the groups and users section and it won’t let me. It’s greyd out. What’s  odd is the login for it is the same as my husband’s login. I’m the administrator but typing in his name and password for his own login works for it. It’s like a duplicate of his profile on my computer. The wallpaper is even the same. But the login screen has it listed as other. I also have been trying to get rid of this stupid websearchstride pop up problem. Idk if it’s all related or not. The system has been updated. I tried to get Bitdefender to scan my computer. Said it got rid of stuff but I’m steal dealing with issues. TIA.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/232449/18101) help you?